# Can't use nvidia-smi with nvidia 495 driver Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, ubuntu-drivers

I encountered a problem while trying to install my GPU drivers.

I installed the 495 NVIDIA driver. Which was the recommended driver for Ubuntu.

Somehow, nvidia-smi doesn’t find the driver I installed. Yet, the driver is present when running DKMS status:

```
user@server:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

user@server:~$ dkms status
nvidia, 495.29.05, 5.11.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed

user@server:~$ nvidia-debugdump -l
Error: nvmlInit(): Driver Not Loaded

user@server:~$ lspci -v | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 Rev. A] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

I also get this:

```
user@server:~$ systemctl status nvidia-persistenced.service
● nvidia-persistenced.service - NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-12-06 14:50:17 EST; 38min ago
    Process: 1109 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --verbose (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Process: 1116 ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -rf /var/run/nvidia-persistenced/* (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 06 14:50:17 server systemd[1]: nvidia-persistenced.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 06 14:50:17 server systemd[1]: Stopped NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
Dec 06 14:50:17 server systemd[1]: nvidia-persistenced.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 06 14:50:17 server systemd[1]: nvidia-persistenced.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 06 14:50:17 server systemd[1]: Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
```

My GPU is detected. Am I missing a step required to link nvidia-smi to the Ubuntu NVIDIA driver?

I have a `xorg.conf` file, with which I am able to set a resolution size, but not connect it to nvidia-smi.

Let me know if you need more info on this issue.

Thank you in advance.

(Edit):

Here is `sudo lshw -c video`

```
user@server:~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 Rev. A]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: I used `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-495` after seeing it in `ubuntu-drivers devices`. I also purged my drivers multiple times, which might mean some blacklists are hidden somewhere. I found this similar issue: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-driver-is-not-loaded-ubuntu-18-10/70495

Comment: You can reply in your original posting, comments may be deleted.  Definitely check for anything other than nvidiafb (fgrep nvidia /etc/modprobe.d/*) -- shouldn't be any.  What driver does lshw -c video show? Add it's text output to your original posting with code tags. Is secure boot off?   A Windows update might turn it back on.

Comment: Thanks! I just updated the post with `lshw`

Comment: Nvidia 495 is beta software. Purge it, and install 470.86... or whatever the most recent version that ends in a zero. Use `Software & Updates` Additional Drivers tab, or see https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/. You may also have to disable Secure Boot in your BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

As heynnema said,

I disabled Secure boot in my UEFI bios. `nvidia-smi` now works perfectly fine!

```
user@server:~$ nvidia-smi
Mon Dec  6 18:14:06 2021
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 495.29.05    Driver Version: 495.29.05    CUDA Version: 11.5     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   49C    P8    17W / 190W |    179MiB /  5931MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1152      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 35MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1889      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 48MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2016      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               84MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You mean you disabled Secure Boot, right ? Because deleting all keys will indeed put Secure Boot in _Setup Mode_ hence stop SB enforcement, but that's a bit harsh and requires repopulating the keys databases later, should you decide to reenable it. Imho, the best way to disable Secure Boot checks on Ubuntu is to execute `mokutil --disable-validation`. But anyway, it should work with Secure Boot, you probably lack a module signature key : `update-secureboot-policy --new-key`